# "No such file or directory" when trying to build ecolab

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, compiling

Im trying to build ecolab.5.D19 but I get error message "No such file or directory" even if the directories and files exists, and im in the same folder as MAKEFILE. I use the following command, which is adviced in installation-guide:

```
sudo make install PREFIX=/usr/local/ecolab
```

I get errors such as:

```
ecolab.5.D19/include/Makefile.config: No such file or directory
Makefile:165: src/automorph.d: No such file or directory
Makefile:165: src/auxil.d: No such file or directory
Makefile:165: src/arrays.d: No such file or directory
Makefile:165: src/sparse_mat.d: No such file or directory etc.
```

Then it freezes after this:

```
rm: cannot remove 'functiondb.h': No such file or directory
make[1]: [functiondb.h] Error 1 (ignored)
sh functiondb.sh >functiondb.h
```

All those files are there.

I have ubuntu 14.04 64-bit with 3.13.0-39-lowlatency
kernel and it seems that this problem can appear when installing 32-bit programs on a 64-bit system. I installed the 32-bit libraries but it did not solve the problem. Dependencies should be fine.
I am trying to install minksy ­-- which requires ecolab. Thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate issue appears to be that the `functiondb.sh` script uses bash features, however the Makefile that invokes it does so explicitly using `sh` (and /bin/sh is a symlink to dash in Ubuntu). Specifically, the `++` postfix operator isn't supported, so counters aren't incrementing and the script gets stuck in a while loop.

You can either temporarily symlink /bin/sh to bash, or modify the /classdesc/Makefile, replacing

```
functiondb.h: functiondb.sh
    -rm $@
    sh $< >$@
```

by

```
functiondb.h: functiondb.sh
    -rm $@
    bash $< >$@
```

Comment: Well, now it prints in the end:

`sr/local/ecolab/include\" -MM -MG src/xdr_pack.cc src/xdr_pack.d`
`mkdir -p lib`
`mkdir -p bin`
`cd classdesc; make PREFIX=/home/joonas/ecolab.5.D19 install`
`make[1]: Entering directory /home/joonas/ecolab.5.D19/classdesc'`
`Makefile:103: *** missing separator.  Stop.`
`make[1]: Leaving directory /home/joonas/ecolab.5.D19/classdesc'`
`make: *** [/home/joonas/ecolab.5.D19/bin/classdesc] Error 2`

Comment: `Missing separator` usually means you indented the line with spaces instead of using a tab character (`make` insists on tabs - sometimes text editors like to replace them).

Comment: Yep, that was the case, and it did build for a while but problems aren't over:

`ar: creating lib/libecolab.a`
`ar: graphcode/*.{hmap,vmap}: No such file or directory`
`make[1]: *** [lib/libecolab.a] Error 1`
`make[1]: Leaving directory /home/ilari/ecolab.5.D19'`
`make: *** [ecolab-libs] Error 2`

hmap and vmap was there in the folder.

Comment: That's almost certainly for a similar reason: brace expansion like `*.{hmap,vmap}` is valid in bash, but `make` will be using the system /bin/sh, which is dash. You can either edit the top-level Makefile and replace the expansions, or temporarily modify the symlink using `sudo ln -sf bash /bin/sh` before running the `make` command, then restore it when you're done with `sudo ln -sf dash /bin/sh`